# how to plot graphs above each other in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I want to plot two (or more) graphs in Matlab. I want them to be aligned one above the second one above the third and so on. However subplot is not the case for me. I also want them both to be on the same graph in different colors, just to be one above the other. Is it possible? I'm searching for such a command but without any success. Thanks in advance for hints!

Comment: Are both graphs using the same axes? Like, displaying the sin wave and the cosine wave on the same graph?

Comment: The linked duplicate question looks very much like a different question, but my answer there exactly answers your question also (I believe). Look at the second half of the answer, under "**Idea 2**".